# Re-enabling the XCode 4 "show this screen when Xcode starts" checkbox.

Tags: xcode4, startup, splash-screen

I've managed to uncheck the Xcode 4 'show this screen when Xcode starts' checkbox and I want it back again. How is this achieved? I can't see anything in user prefs, nor is there any reference to it in the Xcode 4 documentation - aside from 'starting a new project'. Further, there don't seem to be any existing questions anywhere on Google. If anyone knows where the re-enable checkbox is - please tell me. Thanks again.
V.V.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Choose Window > Welcome to Xcode from the main menu and re-check the "Show this window..." box.